# Error in sending JSON Object from Volley to Nodejs Server

Tags: android, json, node.js, authorization, android-volley

I am trying to send a JSON object to server using Volley library in Android. My android code is:

```
public void userRecord(String facebook_id, String full_name, String email, String gender){
    Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    userInfo.put("facebook_id", facebook_id);
    userInfo.put("full_name", full_name);
    userInfo.put("email", email);
    userInfo.put("gender", gender);
    String userRecordsUrl =  getResources().getString(R.string.production_url) + "/userRecord";

    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, userRecordsUrl,
            new JSONObject(userInfo),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
            return headers;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

The corresponding part written in Sailjs running the nodeJS server is:

```
userRecord: function(req, res){
    var facebook_id = req.body.facebook_id;
    var full_name = req.body.full_name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var gender= req.body.gender;
    conn.query('CALL fx_user_record (?, ?, ?, ?)', [facebook_id, full_name, email, gender], function(err, user_record){
        if(err){
            res.serverError(err);
        }else{          
            var user_id = JSON.stringify(user_record[0][0].id)
            res.json({"user_id":user_id});
        }
    });
},
```

But whenever I execute this server call on Android, I get the following error in server log:

```
error: Server Error:
error: UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
    at middleware (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/n                                                                                                                ode_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:79:21)
    at Object.handle (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/marril                                                                                                                y/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/express-unless/index.js:47:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node_mo                                                                                                                dules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:169:15)
    at Object.xPoweredBy [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/ma                                                                                                                rrily-api/test/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/middleware/defaults.js:193:7                                                                                                                )
    at next (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node_mo                                                                                                                dules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:169:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-de                                                                                                                v/test-api/test/node_modules/sails/node_modules/method-override/index.js:6                                                                                                                3:14)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node_mo                                                                                                                dules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:169:15)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node_mo                                                                                                                dules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:171:9)
    at Object._parseHTTPBody [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-de                                                                                                                v/test-api/test/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/index.js:62:14)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node_mo                                                                                                                dules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:169:15)
    at /home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node_modules/                                                                                                                sails/lib/hooks/http/middleware/defaults.js:52:22
    at session (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node                                                                                                                _modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/express-se                                                                                                                ssion/index.js:318:7)
    at Object._.defaults.session [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/test-server/marril                                                                                                                y-dev/test-api/test/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/middleware/defaults.                                                                                                                js:50:11)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node_mo                                                                                                                dules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:169:15)
    at Object.cookieParser [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/                                                                                                                test-api/test/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect                                                                                                                /node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:34:14)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/test-server/test-dev/test-api/test/node_mo                                                                                                                dules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:169:15) { [Un                                                                                                                authorizedError: No authorization token was found]
  name: 'UnauthorizedError',
  message: 'No authorization token was found',
  code: 'credentials_required',
  status: 401,
  inner: { message: 'No authorization token was found' } }
```

Any hint on what I am missing or how to overcome this?

Comment: It seems that the service which have you connected to requires authorization (you should get the same error on the server side (in line res.serverError(err);))

Comment: @SeanDoe I am getting this error on the server side itself. It is server log from the res.servererror, that I have posted. What steps shall I take so that requests are authorized and I post the data properly to the server?

Comment: It depends where do you connect to make a query (conn.query) - this service requires authorization and you have to configure it or get credentials. Is it some database?

Comment: @SeanDoe yes, conn.query connects to the mysql database. But that database is authorized and I can write and retrieve entries into and from the database if I dont use JSON object and instead I send data through URL as parameters in the URL across the same nodejs server